# How to repair window balance when steel coil disengaged from weight?

Tags: windows

When I open this window the sash falls right by down and I took a look at it today. When I checked the balances, the steel coil had fully detached from the balance and was sliding up and down with the balance shoe. Any ideas on how to reengage the coil?[image]

Answer (score 1):

The two Philips screw are responsible for that.

Loosen them (do not unscrew)

Slide them back (towards center)

Bring the steel coil in the position and slide back the screws and tighten.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually possible to fix, but repair of each type of window is different. Some suggestions:

- If the window are removable (e.g., by latches, or by pushing sideways against the vertical rail until the opposite side pops free), do so *carefully*.
- Search for repair info by make and model, if possible.
- Find a diagram for your particular type of window system, such as these generic diagrams at [Brennan](https://brennancorp.com/blog/window-balances-101/), this [Swissco video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkSl9mC6aIA), or this [Amsco video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xc4qWX3Gwdo).
- If the top of the spring has simply become detached, not broken, it can be reattached.
- On a window that had a long coil spring, I found the spring broke at the top turn. The spring was removed, heated briefly a the last turn with a torch, and the turn bent at 90° to form a loop attachment point.
- It might be that the mechanism will have to be removed and replaced. Some can be found online, such as this [Caldwell 29" spring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005OBRMQU).